# MySQL: Disparador que combine varias operaciones DML

Tags: mysql, trigger

¿Es posible crear disparadores en MySQL que se ejecuten tanto ante un INSERT como ante un DELETE como ante un UPDATE?

Estoy intentando hacer un disparador muy sencillo (hace año y pico que no "programo" en MySQL), que cuente y sume el número de votos en una tabla, calcule la media y apunte los resultados en otra, pero necesitaría que lo hiciera tanto si se ha insertado un nuevo registro como si se ha borrado o actualizado uno antiguo; algo así, que es la versión `INSERT`, pero para las tres operaciones DML:

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER votacion

    AFTER INSERT ON votan FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN

        SET @votos = (SELECT count(nota) FROM votan WHERE id_cancion = NEW.id_cancion);
        SET @nota_total = (SELECT sum(nota) FROM votan WHERE id_cancion = NEW.id_cancion);

        SET @nota_media = @nota_total / @votos;

        UPDATE canciones SET votos_web = @votos WHERE id_cancion = NEW.id_cancion;
        UPDATE canciones SET nota_media = @nota_media WHERE id_cancion = NEW.id_cancion;

    END;

$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Claro, para un `DELETE` no serviría `NEW`, sino que tendría que ser `OLD`... Y, en cualquier caso, si intento algo como `AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON votan FOR EACH ROW` -como he visto en algún artículo que he encontrado gugleando- me da un error de sintaxis (la versión del servidor MySQL es la 5.7.26).

¿Hay alguna alternativa elegante que combine las tres posibilidades o tendría que hacer tres disparadores distintos?

¿O me olvido de MySQL y lo hago con PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Una opción a evaluar (siempre que sea factible poder crear procedimientos almacenados y disparadores en la base de datos) puede ser crear un procedimiento almacenado (stored procedure) que encapsule todas las operaciones DML necesarias y luego en cada disparador (trigger) invocar dicho procedimiento almacenado pasando los parámetros necesarios ya sea usando NEW u OLD, evitando triplicar la lógica de las operaciones DML.

Answer (score 0):

Si analizas [la sintaxis de `CREATE TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) puedes ver lo siguiente:

```
trigger_event: { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }
```

Los símbolos `|` significan `OR` lo cual quiere decir que MySQL no soporta la creación de `TRIGGER` para eventos múltiples.

Esto se puede ver también en el [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-infoschema-excerpt/8.0/en/triggers-table.html) relativo a los `TRIGGERS`:

> `EVENT_MANIPULATION`
>
> The trigger event. This is the type of operation on the associated
>   table for which the trigger activates. The value is `INSERT` (a row
>   was inserted), `DELETE` (a row was deleted), or `UPDATE` (a row was
>   modified).

En la constitución de MySQL no están contemplados `TRIGGER` multieventos, en parte por el mismo problema que planteas en la pregunta:

> Claro, para un `DELETE` no serviría `NEW`, sino que tendría que ser `OLD`...

Son tres eventos distintos, no hay por qué tratarlos en un solo disparador, por tanto, es necesario crear un `TRIGGER` propio para cada evento: `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` Siempre será una mejor opción que meterte a programar en PHP algo que es más propio de la base de datos o recurrir a soluciones oscuras y enrevesadas por no escribir tres consultas ¿...?

Comment: Lo de PHP lo digo porque alguna vez he leído que ciertos alojamientos web no permiten el uso de disparadores en la base de datos, salvo para usuarios con privilegios, y que por eso es preferible codificarlo fuera.

Comment: @JavierBlanco si no se permiten desde dentro de la BD, veo difícil que lo puedas hacer desde fuera ¿?

Comment: @wchiquito no es lo mismo. El OP preguntaba por un `TRIGGER` que combine varias operaciones DML. Lo que el enlace dice es esto: *A partir de MySQL 5.7.2, es posible definir múltiples disparadores para una tabla dada que tengan el mismo evento disparador y tiempo de acción. Por ejemplo, puede tener dos disparadores `BEFORE UPDATE` para una tabla.* Los enlaces de mi respuesta son de la última versión de MySQL, la sintaxis no admite múltiples eventos DML.

Comment: @JavierBlanco: Efectivamente, lo indicado por @A.Cedano, es correcto, actualmente MySQL no tiene soporte para que un mismo disparador (trigger) se active a más de una acción DML (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` o `DELETE`). Otros productos si lo permiten. Eliminaré mi comentario anterior para no generar confusión. Gracias @A.Cedano.